# Using GPU despite setting CPU_Only, yielding unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, caffe

I'm installing Caffe on an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual server with CUDA installed (without driver) using https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-VirtualBox-VM as inspiration. During the installation process I edited the MakeFile to include `"CPU_ONLY := 1"` before building it. However, it seems that Caffe is still trying to make use of the GPU. When I try to run a test example I get the following error:

```
python python/classify.py examples/images/cat.jpg foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python/classify.py", line 130, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "python/classify.py", line 103, in main
    channel_swap=channel_swap)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gpu'
```

How can I fix this and run entirely on CPU?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm gonna add a few words to Mailerdaimon's answer.

I followed the installation guide (https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-VirtualBox-VM) to setup Caffe in my vagrant virtual machine. FYI, virtual machines DO NOT support GPU accelerating. Back to the point, after I fix 'CPU / GPU switch in example scripts'(https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/2058) and add '--print_results --labels_file' options(https://github.com/jetpacapp/caffe/blob/master/python/classify.py) to 'python/classify.py', this command './python/classify.py ./examples/images/cat.jpg foo --print_results' still throws the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python/classify.py", line 175, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "./python/classify.py", line 129, in main
    channel_swap=channel_swap)
  File "/home/vagrant/caffe/python/caffe/classifier.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.transformer.set_mean(in_, mean)
  File "/home/vagrant/caffe/python/caffe/io.py", line 267, in set_mean
    raise ValueError('Mean shape incompatible with input shape.')
  ValueError: Mean shape incompatible with input shape.
```

Then I dump the shape of 'mean'(which is 3*256*256) and 'input'(3*227*227). Obviously these two shapes are incompatible. But old versions of 'set_mean()' do NOT throw the error, so I dig into the python code and find out that old 'set_mean()' function looks like this(python/caffe/pycaffe.py, line 195-202, https://github.com/jetpacapp/caffe/):

```
if mode == 'elementwise':
    if mean.shape != in_shape[1:]:
        # Resize mean (which requires H x W x K input in range [0,1]).
        m_min, m_max = mean.min(), mean.max()
        normal_mean = (mean - m_min) / (m_max - m_min)
        mean = caffe.io.resize_image(normal_mean.transpose((1,2,0)),
                in_shape[2:]).transpose((2,0,1)) * (m_max - m_min) + m_min
```

But in latest Caffe, contributors encapsulate 'set_mean()' and other transformation functions into class 
'Transformer'. New 'set_mean()' function looks like this(python/caffe/io.py, line 253-254, https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/):

```
if ms != self.inputs[in_][1:]:
    raise ValueError('Mean shape incompatible with input shape.')
```

Jesus, how could these two be the same function? So I change the new 'set_mean()', comment out the error raising sentence, and add shape re-sizing procedure as in old 'set_mean()'.

```
if ms != ins:
    print(self.inputs[in_])
    in_shape = self.inputs[in_][1:]
    m_min, m_max = mean.min(), mean.max()
    normal_mean = (mean - m_min) / (m_max - m_min)
    mean = resize_image(normal_mean.transpose((1,2,0)),
                        in_shape[1:]).transpose((2,0,1)) * \
                        (m_max - m_min) + m_min
    '''
    raise ValueError('Mean shape incompatible with input shape.')
    '''
```

Voila, problem solved.

```
Classifying 1 inputs.
Done in 1.17 s.
[('tabby', '0.27933'), ('tiger cat', '0.21915'), ('Egyptian cat', '0.16064'), ('lynx', '0.12844'), ('kit fox', '0.05155')]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "So I change the new 'set_mean()'"? What exactly did you changed?

Comment: Sure. I have added details of my change which is quite naive as you can see :)

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems currently due to a lot of interface changes introduced by the caffe developers. The Python Wrapper is not yet updated with these changes.

See this PR which fixes the problem: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/1964

Answer (score 2):

The same error was solved in another google group:-

Where all you need to do is to change this:

```
 mean=np.load(mean_file)
```

to this:

```
mean=np.load(mean_file).mean(1).mean(1)
```

[Google Group: Mean shape incompatible with input shape](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/C1J5cO54oRE/bSOT3EViAgAJ)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But currently this line looks like <br>`mean  = caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(a)[0]`. I simply add another line after this one <br> `mean = mean.mean(1).mean(1)`

Answer (score 0):

just one typo from user2696499

```
if ms != inputs[in_][1:]
    print(self.inputs[in_])
    in_shape = self.inputs[in_][1:]
    m_min, m_max = mean.min(), mean.max()
    normal_mean = (mean - m_min) / (m_max - m_min)
    mean = resize_image(normal_mean.transpose((1,2,0)),
                        in_shape[1:]).transpose((2,0,1)) * \
                        (m_max - m_min) + m_min
    '''
    raise ValueError('Mean shape incompatible with input shape.')
    '''
```