# Mean shape incompatible with input shape -- CAFFE Classification Error in IO.PY

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm installed Caffe on an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual server with CUDA installed (without driver) using [this link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-VirtualBox-VM).

The classification step:

```
python python/classify.py --print_results examples/images/cat.jpg foo
```

yields a traceback.

I followed the steps as describe is by user2696499 in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692209/using-gpu-despite-setting-cpu-only-yielding-unexpected-keyword-argument/28979649#28979649),
However the variable `ins` is not defined. How or where to define it ?

Answer (score 0):

`ins` stands for the input shape and is equal to `in_shape[1:]`.